# Sending email headers

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have such code for send email:

```
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
```

before that I check whether the email is correct so it has to be.
Then I send an email:

```
$sent = wp_mail($newTo, $subject, $companyName . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $phoneNumber . "\n" . strip_tags($message) . "\n" . $outputMail, $headers);
```

and it doesn't work. I've tried change headers to:

```
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n\\";
```

and then it works. Why my code does't work? I need to provide that email retreived from form.

Comment: Did you set up PHP for sending mail? Did you check your spam filter?

Comment: You were right. I checked server settings and the only allowed protype was: From: "My Name" <sample@email.com>. Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

******Ive edited the code******

```
$from = "your@mail.com";
    $to = "to@mail.com";
    $message = "Message";
    $subject = 'subject';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    if(mail($from, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        //success
    }else{
        //error
    }
```

Comment: Returns true but I've received nothing on my email.

Comment: If you will not use SMTP (PHPmailer) mail send, it will probably go to spam.
I recommend you to try again and just recheck the "from" and the "to".
**The code above works for me, but often users complain that it reaches spam.
**edit: the funtion is incorrect, try to put the var "to" instead of "email".